# Keep on getting junk emails, is it mean that reCaptcha in the form is not working?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a contact us form developed in Kentico CMS, with Google reCaptcha (One checkbox with "I'm not a robot" challenge) integrated.

I keep getting form submissions with new details, mainly advts for online pharma pills and loans.

I am adding words from these submissions to a list of entries. The list of entries are validated against, and any new form submission with these words is blocked.

The contact us input text keeps changing.

I have tracked the IP and browser properties. The below properties are from junk mails.

The IP is not repeated for most submissions.
The browser info is of the sort

Name = Firefox,Type = Firefox37,Version = 37.0,....Platform = Win2000,Is Beta = False,Is Crawler = False,....,Is Win32 = True,...,Supports Cookies = True,....Supports JavaScript = ,3.0,...

or

Name = Chrome,Type = Chrome63,Version ....Platform = WinNT,.......,Supports JavaScript Version = 1.7

Is the reCaptcha broken, or is it an actual person browsing the site and making these submissions?
How can I find out, and avoid these submissions?